# Вычислить скользящее среднее

Tags: python, pandas, машинное-обучение, dataframe, numpy

Есть датафрейм вида.

```
Id  Sequence
3   1,3,13...
7   1,2,1,...
8   1,2,4,...
11  1,8,25...
13  1,111,..
```

Где id - номер последовательности, sequence - последовательность с некоторой закономерностью. Общая задача - угадать следующее число последовательности. Но сейчас я пока разбираюсь со следующим:

Расположив последовательности в столбец, разбив их по запятой, имеется следующий вывод:

```
Id  3   7   8   11  13  15  16  18  20  21  ... 227677  227679  227680  227681  227682  227683  227684  227686  227689  227690
0   1   1   1   1   1   1   840 1   4   1   ... 12  1   1   7   1   0   0   0   2   5
1   3   2   2   8   111 1   1320    2   6   2   ... 50  1   6   7   0   0   -1  1   3   7
2   13  1   4   25  12211   1   1680    7   8   1   ... 113 2   45  3   1   4   -1  9   3   179
```

То есть траспонировали датафрейм. Теперь следующая проблема

Метод для вычисления скользящей средней:

```
def moving_average(series, n):
    return np.average(series[-n:])

moving_average(dftrain[3], 24)
```

Здесь я подаю пока что только 1 столбец для теста, хотя на самом деле вызов должен быть в цикле for для каждого существующего столбца. Так вот
В последовательности имеются Слишком большие числа, поэтому необходимо отсечь из каждого столбца все числа, которые больше скажем некоторого X. Также проблема в том, что в столбцах значения None, метод не может сложить два None числа, я пытался заменить None на 0, но по-моему это неверно

```
dftrain.replace(None, 0)
```

Для тех кому мало данных. Данная тема является продолжением [этой (Тык)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/921844/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-csv-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%86/921882)

Вопроса 2. Как исключить большие числа из стобцов и как избавиться с проблемой с None. Чтобы метод скользящее среднее отработал нормально

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Чтобы заменить числа состоящие из более чем 12 цифр на бесконечность, а строковые значения `None` на `NaN` (Not a Number):

```
import pandas as pd

def strip_big_nums(col, maxlen=12):
    return pd.to_numeric(np.where(col.str.len() > maxlen, 
                                  'inf', col), 
                         errors='coerce')

train = pd.read_csv(r'C:\download\train.csv', sep=",", index_col=['Id'])
r = train['Sequence'].str.split(',', expand=True)
r = r.apply(lambda col: strip_big_nums(col, 12))
```

получилось:

```
In [8]: r
Out[8]:
          0       1        2          3            4             5             6             7   ...   340  341  342  343  344  345  346  347
Id                                                                                               ...
3         1.0     3.0     13.0       87.0       1053.0  2.857600e+04  2.141733e+06  5.081471e+08 ...   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
7         1.0     2.0      1.0        5.0          5.0  1.000000e+00  1.100000e+01  1.600000e+01 ...   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
8         1.0     2.0      4.0        5.0          8.0  1.000000e+01  1.600000e+01  2.000000e+01 ...   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
11        1.0     8.0     25.0       83.0        274.0  2.275000e+03  1.322240e+05  1.060067e+06 ...   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
13        1.0   111.0  12211.0  1343211.0  147753211.0  1.625285e+10           inf           inf ...   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
15        1.0     1.0      1.0        1.0          1.0  1.000000e+00  1.000000e+00  1.000000e+00 ...   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
16      840.0  1320.0   1680.0     2520.0       3192.0  3.432000e+03  4.920000e+03  5.208000e+03 ...   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
...       ...     ...      ...        ...          ...           ...           ...           ... ...   ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...
227681    7.0     7.0      3.0        2.0          3.0  9.000000e+00  5.000000e+00  4.000000e+00 ...   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
227682    1.0     0.0      1.0        0.0          0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00 ...   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
227683    0.0     0.0      4.0     1198.0    1829388.0  2.379604e+10           inf           inf ...   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
227684    0.0    -1.0     -1.0       -1.0         -1.0  1.032430e+07           inf           inf ...   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
227686    0.0     1.0      9.0       85.0        801.0  7.549000e+03  7.114500e+04  6.705010e+05 ...   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
227689    2.0     3.0      3.0        4.0          6.0  4.000000e+00  5.000000e+00  1.000000e+01 ...   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
227690    5.0     7.0    179.0      229.0        439.0  5.570000e+02  6.113000e+03  2.239990e+05 ...   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN

[113845 rows x 348 columns]
```

далее данный DF можно транспонировать:

```
In [9]: r.T
Out[9]:
Id      3       7       8         11            13      15      16       ...    227681  227682        227683        227684   227686  227689  227690
0          1.0     1.0     1.0       1.0  1.000000e+00     1.0   840.0   ...       7.0     1.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00      0.0     2.0     5.0
1          3.0     2.0     2.0       8.0  1.110000e+02     1.0  1320.0   ...       7.0     0.0  0.000000e+00 -1.000000e+00      1.0     3.0     7.0
2         13.0     1.0     4.0      25.0  1.221100e+04     1.0  1680.0   ...       3.0     1.0  4.000000e+00 -1.000000e+00      9.0     3.0   179.0
3         87.0     5.0     5.0      83.0  1.343211e+06     1.0  2520.0   ...       2.0     0.0  1.198000e+03 -1.000000e+00     85.0     4.0   229.0
4       1053.0     5.0     8.0     274.0  1.477532e+08     1.0  3192.0   ...       3.0     0.0  1.829388e+06 -1.000000e+00    801.0     6.0   439.0
5      28576.0     1.0    10.0    2275.0  1.625285e+10     1.0  3432.0   ...       9.0     0.0  2.379604e+10  1.032430e+07   7549.0     4.0   557.0
6    2141733.0    11.0    16.0  132224.0           inf     1.0  4920.0   ...       5.0     0.0           inf           inf  71145.0     5.0  6113.0
..         ...     ...     ...       ...           ...     ...     ...   ...       ...     ...           ...           ...      ...     ...     ...
341        NaN     NaN     NaN       NaN           NaN     NaN     NaN   ...       NaN     NaN           NaN           NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN
342        NaN     NaN     NaN       NaN           NaN     NaN     NaN   ...       NaN     NaN           NaN           NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN
343        NaN     NaN     NaN       NaN           NaN     NaN     NaN   ...       NaN     NaN           NaN           NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN
344        NaN     NaN     NaN       NaN           NaN     NaN     NaN   ...       NaN     NaN           NaN           NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN
345        NaN     NaN     NaN       NaN           NaN     NaN     NaN   ...       NaN     NaN           NaN           NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN
346        NaN     NaN     NaN       NaN           NaN     NaN     NaN   ...       NaN     NaN           NaN           NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN
347        NaN     NaN     NaN       NaN           NaN     NaN     NaN   ...       NaN     NaN           NaN           NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN

[348 rows x 113845 columns]
```

Comment: Кто как не вы) Спасибо за помощь, при попытке скормить данные функции на выходе Nan. Мне уже начинает казаться, что невозможно посчитать=)  Наверное он суммирует с Nan и результат Nan) Я подавал только 1 столбец (номер 3)

Comment: @StenFord, да, если суммтрвать NaN с любым числом - результат будет NaN. Поэтому с NaN, наверное, придется что-то делать...

Comment: Были попытки заменить Nan на 0 (df.replace). Не вышло) Хотя это и не очень хорошая идея, ибо нули могут восприниматься как часть последовательности